# How to efficiently filter datetime column for extracting data?

Tags: php, sql

I am usng sqlite to log data every 5 minutes to a column that is time stamped with and integer in Unix time. The user interface uses php code to extract data in various user selectable time frames which is then plotted using javascript. Charts typically have 12 data/time points and I need to extract data for plotting over different periods of say 1Hr/12Hr/24Hr/12days/month/year. So  only need to extract 12 data rows per search. So for a 24Hr plot I need to only extract data at houly intervals (when minutes = 0) similarly for 12day plots at daily intervals (when mins=0 && hours=0) etc.

My php code for 1Hr works fine since the data is logged every 5min giving me 12 rows of data between search start time and end time. What is an efficient way of extracting data for the longer periods when number of rows between start time and end time is greater than 12? I need to further filter the search to efficiently extract only the data I need?

any suggestions - most appreciated - frank

```
$db = new MyDB();                                    // open database
$t=time(); // get current time
$q1 = "SELECT TimeStamp,myData FROM mdata WHERE ";
$q2 = " AND TimeStamp <=".$t;                        // end time
$q3 = " AND TimeStamp >=".($t-3600);                 // start time 1 hour earlier

$qer = $q1.$q2.$q3; // my search query form above parts

$result = $db->query($qer);
$json = array();
while ($data = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE_NUM)) {
$json[] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($json);             // data is returned as json array


$db->close();           // close database connection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WHERE date BETWEEN in your search query?
This kind of search could take up a lot of time once data builds up?

Comment: Thanks SYNENERGY - not sure what you mean?

Comment: Thanks SYNENERGY - not sure what exactly you mean?
Been trying to find a solution for days, I am new to sql - don't see why an "expert" who probably finds the question really simple would give it a bad vote though?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the exact times you're interested in, you should probably just build an array of times and use [SQL's `IN` operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
$db = new MyDB();                                    // open database
$timeStep = 300;  // Time step to use, 5 minutes here - this would be 3600 for hourly data
$t = time(); // get current time
$t -= $t % $timeStep;  //  round to the proper interval

$query  = "SELECT TimeStamp,myData FROM mdata ";
$query .= "WHERE TimeStamp IN "
$query .= "(" . implode(",", range($t, $t + $timeStep * 12, $timeStep)) . ")";    

$result = $db->query($query);
$json = array();
while ($data = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE_NUM)) {
    $json[] = $data;
}
```

You'll need to do some different math for monthly data - try constructing 12 times with PHP's [`mktime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function.

Here are the references for the PHP [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) functions I used.